# Karaf bundle can not find Log4j LogManager.class in the run time.

Tags: logging, log4j, karaf, pax

Currently I am working on a project which I need to wave third party JAR into our Karaf D-OSGi application.   We aren't suppose to change any code inside the jar, but with limited source code we can debug into it.

The issue is that the third party jar depends on log4j-1.2.9 jar.   however when the third party jar was called in the running time ,  logManager.class can not be found from the third party jar.

### here is the exception logs from Karaf.

```
karaf@root()> lde
```

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org/apache/log4j/LogManager
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)[166:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.7]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)[166:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.7]
        ...
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[115:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[115:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager
        at com.p*******h.eis.tools.logging.LoggingSetup.isConfigured(LoggingSetup.java:77)
        at com.p*******h.o****l.sdk.configurator.Configurator.checkLogging(Configurator.java:623) (------------inside the third party jar------------------)
        at com.p*******h.o****l.sdk.configurator.Configurator.load(Configurator.java:383)
        at com.p*******h.o****l.sdk.configurator.Configurator.getInstance(Configurator.java:72)
        at com.p*******h.o****l.sdk.transactionProcessor.TransactionProcessor.(TransactionProcessor.java:43)
        at ca.esc.pbm.integr.chase.provider.service.PbmChaseApiImpl.getCCtokenFromChasePaymentGateWay(PbmChaseApiImpl.java:98)

```
    ... 36 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.LogManager not found by org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [1]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
        ...
        ... 50 more

### karaf@root()>

in the bundle ,  pom.xml has log4j 1.2.8 dependency.
 and in bnd.bnd,      Export-Package :  org.apache.log4j.*,  .....

---

I have checked the generated bundle jar from maven, log4j package/jar was imported into the bundle and in the Karaf run time.

I did some debugging/research , looked like Pax logger take over/delegate the Log4j which hide the LogManager from the bundle.

---

Plus, I tried to call LogManager from the bundle directly without involving the third party Jar, I get the same exception that LogManager.class can not be found.

I understand Karaf use Pax logger for logging and delegate log4j implementation to Pax, however in my case how can I let the untouchable Jar class calling the LogManager successfully?

Thanks

Paul N.

Comment: My Karaf version is 4.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that you can check:

Search the class path for the jar file having the logmanager class and try to override with the chase specific log4j jar file.